# Error using Numba in vectorized function in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, numba

I am trying to speed up my code by using Numba, njit, and using parallel function on it.

Here is the code that I write

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
@njit (parallel = True)
def height(ws,water):
    global z,nrows,ncols,dx,r,r1,c,c1
    h = np.zeros((nrows,ncols,4))
    mask = water>0
    for k in range (4):
        h[1:nrows-1,1:ncols-1,k] = np.where(mask[1:nrows-1,1:ncols-1],ws[1:nrows-1,1:ncols-1]-np.maximum(z[1:nrows-1,1:ncols-1],z[r[k]:nrows+r1[k],c[k]:ncols+c1[k]]),0)
        h = np.where(h<0.00001,0,h)
    return h
```

where ws, water, and z is 2D array; nrows and ncols are number of rows and columns, dx is constant, r,r1,c,c1 are tuples like (0,1,3,4)

when I tried to run it, it always shows error like this:

**Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: convert to parfors)
object of type 'NoneType' has no len()**

here are the parameters:

```
r = (0,1,2,1)
r1 = (-2,-1,0,-1)
c = (1,2,1,0)
c1 = (-1,0,-1,-2)
dx = 5
nrows = z.shape[0]
ncols = z.shape[1]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of parameters? And your code needs to be improved.

Comment: Already edit the original script sir.

Comment: Needs ```z ws water```. Or you can simply describe your intentions.

Comment: well z, ws, and water is 2D array. we can create it simply using numpy

Comment: btw, `global z,nrows,ncols,dx,r,r1,c,c1` doesn't do anything useful

Comment: Also, those aren't parameters.

Comment: yes. they are acting as the constant parameters. since I have to repeatedly call this function through a loop

Comment: The code is working fine.

Comment: the code is working fine, but when I added @njit at the top, it becomes an error.